# Wirelessly activate devices using light weight and low-power solution

Tags: switches, wireless, rf, infrared

I have several circuits which I need to turn on and off wirelessly. 
The rules are:

1. They are placed inside a transparent small box (about 50x50x50 cm)
2. The control unit\transmitter can be placed anywhere outside the box, and has no power\shape\size\cost limitations
3. I have about 10 circuits which need to be turned on and off individually. Each circuit has it's own set of batteries (3 x 1.5v) and consumes about 1.7mw
4. It has to be very low weight - less then a gram
5. Very low power consumption - on the orders of milliwatts

I have two directions, but not a good way to implement any of them. 
The first is to use IR with modulation, and the second is to use RF.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the range?

Comment: Less than a gram probably eliminates any canned modules with RF protocol, like WiFi or MiWi.  IR is probably the best to look into if line and distance is OK.  Also milliamps is a unit of current, not power.

Comment: Hi Leon and Olin, I've edited the question after your remarks. The transmitter can be anywhere outside the box. And Olin, sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: Haha wireless activation "weight - less than a gram" - how is that even possible?

Comment: Boardbite, I didn't say it was easy... 
For example, I've tried looking at MEMS devices which theoretically can be much lighter.

Comment: Well, the receiver could conceivably be made somewhat lightweight, e.g., even an SMD infrared receiver, assuming it were a part (not separate) of your existing circuit boards in the box. The transmitter would at the very least needs its own power source, which already puts you over your dollar-bill weight limitation.

Comment: What is the voltage and current that needs to be switched to the "circuit"?

Answer (score 1):

What about a photodetector and transistor as the receiver - the transmitter could then be a torch which have to shine on a device to switch it on. This is the simplest solution I can think of.

If you are thinking higher tech communications the lowest power and I suspect lightest RF solution might be a the Texas instruments CC430 Microcontroller which has integrated RF. You could of course remove the packaging to reduce weight.